# How to fix bad drawing menu?

Tags: wingpanel, menu

My menu appears whit like duplicated box in the background on different stiles. Why its this happening? how to fix it?
[image: Example menu]

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It is cause you have multiple extensions added
try installing elementary tweaks using the following commands in
the terminal which you can either open manually or press the windows+t shortcut

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks

then open the tweaker and you should be able to turn it off in additional settings

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tweaks already installed. I'm not sure about which extensions you mean, themes? indicators?

Comment: Desktop extensions to the wingpanel/topbar if you have tweaks there should be an option to turn I off

Comment: I'm really sorry but I don really know about witch extensions are you referring, On tweaker the options are General (appearance,  fonts, animations, shadows, miscellaneous) and Applications (plank, files, slingshot, cerbere, terminal). In no one of those cant  se "extensions". I'm really lost.

Comment: Do you mean system indicators?